# Use sha3 for passwords hashing

Tags: passwords, sha-2, sha-3, password-hashing, keccak

Is use of sha3 justifiable? Is sha3 better than sha2 in (m)any aspects?

P.S. I want to use hashing for passwords in a database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is sha3 better than sha2 in (m)any aspects?

SHA3 is built on-top of a fundamentally different construction than SHA-2 which has many nice properties. So yes, in many hash-function relevant aspects it is indeed better. As for password-hashing, SHA-3 implementations (without hardware acceleration) also tend to be slower, which is good in this case.

**However.**

> Is use of sha3 justifiable?

**NO.** Do not use a *fast* hashing function for password hashing. Use a dedicated *password hashing scheme* (PHS) such as Argon2 or bcrypt. These have been heavily reviewed, analyzed and even been built around the idea of being used for password hashing. They do their job *really* well and give you and your users the best possible security to the standards threats that you have to deal with when handling passwords on standard modern CPUs with fast RAM access.

Comment: Would multiple iterations of some sha-x flavor be sufficient for password hashing? Provided it's slow enough.

Comment: @Q-Club You are describing PBKDF2, which is not memory hard like modern algorithms

Comment: SHA3 is slow in software but fast in hardware, which makes it terrible for password hashing because the attacker has a tremendous advantage

Comment: @RichieFrame Got it, what key size (assume random binary string) would you feel comfortable hashing with sha3?

Comment: @Q-Club 112 bits, which is 19 random alphanumeric characters, but passwords are seldomly random

Comment: I have to agree with @RichieFrame here. SHA-3 is probably the worst choice of a primitive for password hashing. I would go with PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA2 any day over PBKDF2-KMAC-SHA3. I'm almost tempted to -1 because being slower in software and faster in hardware is **not** a good thing for password hashing.

Comment: @forest Well, this assumes your attacker using FPGAs / ASICs for brute-forcing which I would presume is much less common (especially for SHA3) than than using GPUs. But of course this also depends on your attacker. Your average password cracker who goes through password dumps or your average pentester will probably use GPUs and only a _very_ determined attacker will use FPGAs / ASICs. But at that point you probably have other things to worry about or will enforce high entropy passwords anyways.

Comment: If your adversary cannot use hardware acceleration, then the relative software vs hardware advantage is irrelevant and it doesn't matter in the slightest how fast or slow the construction is in software. There's a reason Argon2 (and virtually all the PHC candidates) focused on not being much faster on hardware than software, even though Argon2 is recommended for _everyone_, not just those with ASIC-wielding adversaries.